# validating child properties of model using DataAnnotations or CustomValidation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, customvalidator

i'm working on a MVC3 webapp and my Model consist of many classes that use a custom type for textual properties.
for example my Product entity looks like :

```
public class Product
{
   public int ProductId {get;set;}
   public TextRef Title {get;set;}
   public TextRef Description {get;set;}
}
```

and TextRef is :

```
public class TextRef
{
   public int LangId {get;set;}
   public string Text {get;set;}
}
```

so in my views i'm using :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title.Text)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title.Text)
```

is there a way to enable validation for these TextRef properties using DataAnnotations ?

i didn't find any, so i have created a custom validator attribute:

```
public class TextRefRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value is TextRef)
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextRef)value).Text);
        else
            return true;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        rule.ValidationType = "textref";
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

now the server-side validation is working but client-side isn't. in fact the "data-val-" attributes didn't generated for their inputs.

**UPDATE:**

my client script is :

```
$.validator.addMethod("textref", function (value, element, param) {
    return (value != "");
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("textref");
```

i also tried using FluentValidation:

```
public class CategoryValidator : AbstractValidator<CategoryViewModel>
{
    public CategoryValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(o => o.Title.Text)
            .NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

but still no chance.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The attribute looks ok to me. You will need to register the custom adapter at the client side though which should look a bit like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool('textref');
    });
</script>
```

Which will appear above

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title.Text)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title.Text)
```

Comment: Thanks, actually i have registered the adapter in first place. i find out if i change the EditorFor(model=> model.Title.Text) to TextBoxFor(model=>o.model.Title) the "data-val-" attributes would be added to input elements and client-side validation goes right, but doing so will cause binding problems and the receiving model.Title would be null

Comment: Did you managed to figure out how to solve this? I'm facing the exact same problem, but with the DateTime type where I can't decorate the Date and TimeOfDay properties myself.